# How to read a message only once from a queue

Tags: php, activemq-classic, stomp, php-5.5

I am using ActiveMQ to store a queue of messages.
I am using the PECL Stomp extension to connect to it.
I am publishing to the queue successfully, and reading from it successfuly.
How do I configure the queue to delete a message after I consumed it?
In my listener, I use

```
$c = new Stomp($url);
$c->subscribe('/queue/something');
echo $c->readFrame();
```

Comment: You probably want to acknowledge the consumption of a message. http://php.net/manual/en/stomp.ack.php

Comment: are message not being deleted now?  Please provide more context

Comment: Messages are not being deleted. Each time I disconnect and re-attach to the queue, I get same messages over and over again.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Acknowledging the consumption did the trick. How ever, is there a way to achieve same effect without the extra request? Some of my queues do not need to be very reliable. Maybe some headers in the subscription.

Comment: ok - found it with the keyword u supplied (ack) https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.1.html#SUBSCRIBE

Comment: @CharlotteDunois header = ack: auto -> Why don't you put this and what you wrote  as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to acknowledge the consumption of a message to get them "deleted" from the queue. You can do that with `$stomp->ack($messageID)`.

If you don't want to explicitely acknowledge the receipt, you can set the headers of `$stomp->subscribe` of `ack` to `auto`. This will make the server auto acknowledge the message and assume it was correctly delivered.

```
$stomp->subscribe('/queue/something', array('ack' => 'auto'));
```

References:
http://php.net/manual/en/stomp.ack.php
http://php.net/manual/en/stomp.subscribe.php
https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.1.html#SUBSCRIBE